# Triangulated mesh to Nurbs surface conversion

Tags: mesh, add-on, workflow, conversion, nurbs-surface

I am looking for a feature/workflow/add-on for blender to convert triangulated meshes into a nurbs surfaces.

While looking on the internet for a solution I found [this](http://www.resurf3d.com/mesh2snurbs.htm) software that looks like it does exactly what I would like to do but I would much prefer my entire workflow to be within blender.

Any help, advice or ideas are much appreciated!

Alex